# Attaching an upload to a user

Tags: php, media, user-registration, plugin-gravity-forms

Is there any way with WordPress that a user could upload a file (pdf or jpg, for example) and have that image 'attached' to their account?

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to have a Gravity Forms form that automatically populates the user's name, contact info and this file, kind of like a job site where you can send all your info and your uploaded resume with one click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a single page that doesn't let them register and then asking their First Name, Last Name and other details.

[image]

And then use the field upload in the advance fields

[image]

on the backend view you will be able to see the submission together with their name, address and other details and the file they included in their attachment.

[image]